Host not serving web requests without an active SSH connection
I am self-hosting a Netbird co-ordination server on a ubuntu based Linode VPS environment, and use two Netbird clients where one is installed on the same Linode VPS and the other on a Raspberry Pi 4 device running Raspbian OS - bookworm.
The Traefik application on Linode VPS routes web request to Raspberry Pi 4 via Netbird IP, where the requests are further handled by NGINX proxy manager.
Problem
The web requests to Raspberry Pi works fine initially. But after some time, it becomes unreachable upon a HTTP request. Everything works fine again as soon as I SSH into Raspberry pi via its Netbird IP from Linode VPS.
Raspberry Pi is able to serve HTTP requests made via Netbird IP throughout the period I have an active SSH session on a terminal. When I close the SSH connection, the problem reoccurs after some time. This problem occurred since the inception of my Netbird setup.
Currently, I open an SSH session to Raspberry whenever I want to access my self-hosted services which is very cumbersome. I should be able to make HTTP requests using Netbird IP without the need to constantly open a SSH connection on a separate console window.
What I have tried
Initially I thought the problem was with NGINX Proxy Manager and tried replacing it with Traefik. But surprisingly the problem repeated even with Traefik reverse proxy indicating that the problem is not with the web application I am using.
Later, I thought the problem was with Netbird and replaced it with Headscale which also did not resolve the issue. I am pretty sure that the problem is with my Raspberry Pi.
All the applications and operating systems are up-to-date and running on the latest version.
Note: The HTTP requests by NGINX proxy manager running on Pi4 docker is served (mapped) on non-standard HTTP port 30123 and non standard HTTPS port 30124
